# Make snake effect with liquid effect in triangle border

Tags: javascript, html, css

[I want make like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M0WCq.gif)

I use clip path to draw two triangle inside
and div load to move around small triangle
and use keyframes to make animation by move loading div until angle and make rotate
I need to move like snake and liquid

```css
.wrapper {
  width: auto;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.big-triangle {
  clip-path: polygon(50% 2%, 100% 100%, 0 100%, 50% 2%);
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background: #e3e4e4;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
}

.small-triangle {
  width: 70%;
  height: 73%;
  background: white;
  clip-path: polygon(50% 2%, 100% 100%, 0 100%, 50% 2%);
  position: absolute;
  top: 26px;
}

.load {
  width: 63px;
  height: 15px;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 19px;
  background: linear-gradient(89.82deg, #3adce7 -1.45%, #263aa3 99.84%);
  border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 0;
  animation: loadMove 4s infinite linear;
}

@keyframes loadMove {
  0% {
    /* height: 15px; */
    left: 10px;
  }
  33% {
    left: 90px;
    bottom: 0px;
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: scaleY(2.5);
  }
  39% {
    left: 88px;
    bottom: 39px;
    transform: rotate(63.333deg);
  }
  66% {
    bottom: 110px;
    left: 50px;
    transform: rotate(63.333deg);
  }
  67% {
    bottom: 113px;
    left: 39px;
    transform: rotate(-61.333deg);
  }
  100% {
    bottom: 14px;
    left: -10px;
    transform: rotate(-63.333deg);
  }
}
```

```html
 <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="big-triangle">
        <div class="load"></div>
        <div class="small-triangle"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

my problem
when loading near to angle not be liquid like gif
need to make liquid effect near to triangle angle

Comment: Please read about [How SVG Line Animation Works](https://css-tricks.com/svg-line-animation-works/)

Comment: Indeed, the effect you want is not something you should be using CSS for. SVG would be a much better option.

Comment: @Paulie_D how can do this by svg ?

Answer (score 0):

```css
.wrapper {
  width: auto;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.big-triangle {
  width: 163px;
  height: 145px;
  clip-path: polygon(50% 2%, 100% 100%, 0 100%, 50% 2%);
  background-color: #e3e4e4;
  z-index: 0;
}
.small-triangle {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
}

svg path {
  stroke-width: 20px;
  stroke-dasharray: 50 425;
  animation: a 5s linear infinite;
  stroke-linecap: round;
}

@keyframes a {
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 470;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
      <div class="big-triangle">
        <div class="small-triangle">
          <svg width="160" height="150" viewBox="0 0 189 163" fill="white">
            <defs>
              <linearGradient id="linear" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="100%" y2="0%">
                <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#05a" />
                <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#0a5" />
              </linearGradient>
            </defs>
            <path
              class="path"
              d="M13.5266 155.25L94.5 15L175.473 155.25H13.5266Z"
              stroke="url(#linear)"
              stroke-width="20"
            />
          </svg>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```